# Excel 2007 pivot table - show both grouped and ungrouped data

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have data as below in 3 columns:

[image]

I have created a simple pivot table which looks like this (Invoice Day filtered for days 2 & 4 only):

[image]

I need to modify the pivot to group some rows and display **both** grouped **and** ungrouped data. This would change the Grand Total as well. The Pivot table should look like this after it is grouped:

[image]

I tried working with pivot table options a lot but cannot achieve this. Appreciate any help on this!

Comment: I do not think you will be able to achieve that outcome with a single pivot table because you are asking the pivot table to include some rows of the source data multiple times (e.g. the data for SG on day 2 has to be counted in both the SG and the SG+WI groups). How about one pivot table with the single products (no grand total); another pivot table immediately below with the combined product groups (no grand total); then add your own Grand Total line at the bottom with a simple sum()?

Comment: Yes, it is achievable using 2 pivot tables. But this question was asked in one of the job interviews i attended long time ago. I still could not figure it out how to achieve this in one pivot table. Thanks for your response!

Answer (score 0):

I see that this is an interview question.

What I'd do is adding another column to the source data, say *ProductGroup* which contains `SG+WI` for `SG` and `WI` products, and `CC` for the other product. By dragging the *ProductGroup* field to the pivot table, you will achieve your desired result without getting wrong totals.